# Add link to CSS image

Tags: css, html

I am having some problems trying to add a link to the css image that is after every link, the text itself works but not the image to the right of it, how can I fix it? Thanks.

```
<nav>
    <!-- top menu -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
        <li><a href="materials_list.html">Materials</a></li>
        <li><a href="screened_Loam.html">Screened Loam/Topsoil</a></li>
        <li><a href="RAP.html">RAP</a></li>
        <li><a href="asphalt.html">Asphalt/Concrete Disposals</a></li>
        <li><a href="delivery.html">Delivery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /top menu -->
</nav>

.header nav ul li:after {
    content:'';
    background:url(../images/sprite.png) 6px 7px no-repeat;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
}
```

Comment: What is your output? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: you need to aply your `:after` to `<a>` element, not `<li>`: 

`.header nav ul li a:after { ... }`

Comment: Use this
  <li><a href="index.html"><img src="image url....." height="xxx px" width="XXX px"></a></li>

Comment: @Yukulélé is right. He should add it as an answer. Also, just to point out, you can't add a link to an CSS content, but you can add CSS content to a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your after tag is not apanding to the inner of a tag.

you need to aply your

```
:after to <a> element, not <li>: 
.header nav ul li a:after { ... }
```

so that your image can be inside a tag and your link will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

take this for an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='http://www.google.com'>
        <img src='http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg'>

    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically put your link, then put the img inside of it. Then you could give it a class or id to resize it, move it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you need to apply your `:after` to `<a>` element, not `<li>`

```css
.header nav ul li a:after {
    background-image:url( ... );
}
```

in this way, the image is inside the link

Comment: and is it possible to change the image from been before the text that way? I had on on the li because of that.

Comment: try `:before` instead of `:after`

Comment: Thank you very much, I had done that, but I had not changed the float on the CSS. Again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you're missing an `a` selector in your CSS:

```
.header nav ul li a:after {
    background:url(../images/sprite.png) 6px 7px no-repeat;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
}
```

without the `a` you would be targeting only the `li` directly